# True/False: $a\cdot n^k-b\cdot n^{k-1}=\Omega(n^k)$

Tags: calculus, inequality, solution-verification, data-structure

I need to prove or provide a counter example to this statement:

$a\cdot n^k-b\cdot n^{k-1}=\Omega(n^k)$ while $a,b>0$ and $k \ge 1$.

I think that this one is true, so I want to find $c>0$ and $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that: $0 \le c \cdot n^k \le a\cdot n^k-b\cdot n^{k-1}$.

I can say that $a\cdot n^k-b\cdot n^{k-1} \ge a\cdot n^k-b\cdot n^k=(a-b) \cdot n^k$.

I can't take $c=(a-b)$ because I don't know if $a>b$...

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: You should say, for example, "as $n\to\infty$" if that is what you mean.  Hint.  Computing a certain limit will prove this for you.

Comment: Hint $a-\frac bn>\frac a2$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I can't use limits here...

Comment: You have to realize that the notation $\Omega$ itself is about asymptotic behaviour, so limits will be involved, or at least the construction $\forall n>n_0$ with a $n_0$ function of $a,b,k$.